# Как сохранить текст в поле с помощью localStorage

Tags: html, localstorage

```
<input type="date" class="raz" onchange="localStorage.setItem('server', this.value);">
<input type="button" value="очистить localstorage и перезагрузить страницу" onclick="localStorage.clear(); location.reload();" />
<input type="button" value="удалить localstorage определённого элемента и перезагрузить страницу" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('server'); location.reload();" />
<script>
var dataRaz = document.querySelector('input[type="date"].raz');
if(localStorage.getItem('server') === null) { // если localStorage.getItem пустой
  dataRaz.value = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10); // сегодняшняя дата
} else {
  dataRaz.value = localStorage.getItem('server'); // последняя дата, на которую изменил пользователь
}
</script>
```

как нужно изменить этот код чтобы в текстовое поле можно было ввести свой текст(любой) и чтобы после закрытия страницы , введеный в поле текст сохранился?

Comment: https://myrusakov.ru/html5-local-storage.html Михаил там своими словами объясняет то как пользоваться localstorage , на youtube валом видео по этой тематике

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Me6JVe7V5AI  вот видео - смотрите

Answer (score 1):

```
    <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
<script>
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

function checkValidity() {};

for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
 (function(element) {
   var id = element.getAttribute('id');
   element.value = localStorage.getItem(id); // обязательно наличие у элементов id
   element.oninput = function() {
     localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
     checkValidity();
   };
 })(elements[i]);
}
</script>
```

вот ответ на вопрос но я теперь не знаю как седалать так чтобы сохраненый текст был уникальный для каждой странички

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">

    <script>
    $('.input').change(function(){
      var val_input = $(this).val();
      localStorage.setItem('key', val_input);
    })

    var data = localStorage.getItem('key');  //получаем данные
    </script>
```

Comment: Лучше добавить краткое описание того, что происходит при выполнении этого кода.